# NO PUEDO TRUNCAR UN NUMERO CON MATH.FLOOR EN JAVA

Tags: java

En la linea 25 estoy teniendo problemas con la sintaxis de la funcion Math.floor ya que no puedo truncar el valor para obtener el entero que necesito.

Me esta apareciendo estos mensajes de error y ya no se que mas hacer:

- pro1_3.java:25: error: '.class' expected
  numero_intro = Math.floor(float otro);
  ^
- pro1_3.java:25: error: ';' expected
  numero_intro = Math.floor(float otro);

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class pro1_3{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    String octal = " ";

    int numero_intro = 0,
        res = 0;

    float otro = 0;

    System.out.print("Introduzca numero: ");
    numero_intro = entrada.nextInt();

    while(numero_intro > 0){

        res = numero_intro % 8;
        octal = String.valueOf(res) + octal;

        otro = numero_intro / 8;
        numero_intro = Math.floor(float otro);

    }

    System.out.println("El numero en octal es " + octal);

}
```

}

Comment: `Math.floor(float otro); ` por qué pones float de nuevo?

Answer (score 3):

Estas confundiendo `llamar a un método` con el `desarrollo del método`.

Cuando `llamas a un método` se hace

```
Clase.metodo(dato)
```

Cuando `desarrollas el método` se hace

```
metodo(<tipo_dato> dato)
```

Para tu ejercicio sería

```
numero_intro = Math.floor(otro);
```

Ahora revisando el fin de tu código, lo que quieres es convertir del sistema decimal al sistema octal, lo que hace `Math.floor` es truncar decimales al entero menor más próximo pero el valor que pides por teclado es un número `entero` entonces no vas necesitar truncar nigún número.
Te muestro el código modificado, como podrás observar hay variables que no necesitas inicializar y otras variables que declaras no son necesarias.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        String octal = " ";
        int numero_intro;       

        System.out.print("Introduzca numero: ");
        numero_intro = entrada.nextInt();

        while(numero_intro > 0){            
            octal = numero_intro % 8 + octal;
            numero_intro = numero_intro / 8;           
        }
        System.out.println("El numero en octal es " + octal);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por el código, juraba que tenia que truncarlo aunque no entiendo porque aun poniendo len la linea 25 "umero_intro = Math.floor(otro);" me envía un mensaje de error.

Comment: @plazamarco seguramente te sale error por el tipo de dato, realiza un cast: (int) Math.floor(otro);

Comment: Gracias, agregue "(int)" dejando la linea como "numero_intro = (int) Math.floor(otro);" y si me compilo. Exactamente no entiendo muy bien como se resolvió pero a supongo que a medida que avance con Java lo entenderé mejor. Gracias.

Comment: @plazamarco el error es porque ``Math.floor(otro)`` devuelve un valor decimal y tu variable ``numero_intro`` es entero, por eso necesitabas hacer un ``cast`` para convertir el valor decimal a entero